help with errors in log - GPF
Please help me with following appearing in my logs a few times a day, I dont know where to begin.  24.04 LTS server
2024-12-20T19:29:05.072410-05:00 signalsecurity3 kernel: traps: package-data-do[74336] general protection fault ip:60ff78 sp:7ffd34874108 error:0 in python3.12[420000+2e3000]
2024-12-20T19:29:05.074421-05:00 signalsecurity3 kernel: traps: apport[74337] general protection fault ip:60ff78 sp:7ffc72d90f98 error:0 in python3.12[420000+2e3000]
2024-12-20T19:29:05.074437-05:00 signalsecurity3 kernel: Process 74337(apport) has RLIMIT_CORE set to 1
2024-12-20T19:29:05.074439-05:00 signalsecurity3 kernel: Aborting core
2024-12-20T19:29:05.077810-05:00 signalsecurity3 systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV
2024-12-20T19:29:05.077905-05:00 signalsecurity3 systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
2024-12-20T19:29:05.077948-05:00 signalsecurity3 systemd[1]: Failed to start update-notifier-download.service - Download data for packages that failed at package install time.

If there is a better or more appropriate way to get help diagnosing logs, please educate me.
